# app name displayed in android device

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i am a new developer and i am just trying to create some apps of my own.
In my app i have placed two buttons at the bottom, the problem is the name of my app is been displayed in the top of the page and the main page is not visible fully and so the buttons at bottom are not visible. how to solve this.....

Answer (score 1):

The top bar is controlled using an Activity Theme which you can read more about [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles).

On top of that, you should be using one of the more flexible layouts like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout that will automatically adjust the placement of your items on screen within the available space.  You can read more about those [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to make the title bar (where your app's name appear) go away:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Call it inside `onCreate()`, just after the call to `super.onCreate()`

Avoid using `AbsoluteLayout` and try using `RelativeLayout` in the following way to achieve what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mother_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button Left" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button Rigth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```